# Dynamic content height with min-height

Tags: html, css

I am writing a little browsergame to improve my webskills, but I'm stuck within a layout problem. My gamepage consists of a header, content and a footer with two spacers with a backgroundimage between. The content-div should be stretched vertical, so that the whole space of the view is used. If the content is taller then the browser, it should be stretched further with scrollbars. Its important that the heights are correct, because i use a gradient fill for the background and this shouldn't repeat at some point. I thought i can achieve this with height:auto for content with big size and with min-height:100% for content with small size. But this doesn't work. I read several forum-posts, but nothing is working. Could you help me please? Wheres my error in reasoning?

HTML:
(The br's are used to oversize the page)

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="main">
      Content
      <!--<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>-->
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {

    background: rgb(122,188,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%, rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%, rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(122,188,255,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(96,171,248,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(64,150,238,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7abcff', endColorstr='#4096ee',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.center {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;

    width:1024px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:left;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000;

    background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%, rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%, rgba(117,117,117,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(181,189,200,1)), color-stop(36%,rgba(130,140,149,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(117,117,117,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5bdc8', endColorstr='#757575',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.spacer{
    min-height:16px;
    background-image: url(Absperrband.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #000;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #000;
}

.header {
    padding : 8px;
    height:70px;
}

.main{
    min-height: 100%;
    padding : 12px;
}

.footer{
    padding : 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a 'sticky footer' effect.

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: This solution has the same problem with the body-gradient as the third answer. It isn't stretched, but repeated.

Comment: Not with the CSS adjusted... http://jsfiddle.net/zsmvq/ you'll just need to play with the CSS for the last `spacer` and `footer`

Comment: The grey gradient is all fine, but the blue gradient of the background is repeated. If you resize the width of the resultwindow in your jsfiddle, you can see it. This results of the height:100% of the body. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I worked on this for longer than I care to admit, and I couldn't fix it for both Tall and Short content. So I compromised: Added to `body` `background-repeat:no-repeat`, and a new line of CSS `html { background { background:rgba(64,150,238,1) }` Now there's not a break or a repeat in the gradient of `body` -- it's just not as tall as we'd like it to be. Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TnLh8/

Comment: Good deal. You know, doing it this way also makes the background consistent throughout the site.

Answer (score 0):

html, body should be `height:100%` and your main div (.center) should have the `min-height:100%; height:auto`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDcuZ/)

Comment: This fixes the case with only few content. But with the many br's the gradient of the body isn't stretchet over the whole site, but repeated after the view height.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block;` to the `body` and `.center`
and see the result

Comment: I tried this, but only the centering is destroyed. The height of my elements are unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block;text-align:center;` to the `body`
and `display:inline-block;text-align:left;` to the `.center`

Hope it can fix my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see in this http://jsfiddle.net/PtLYs/, there are no changes of the height with your solution. It seems that changing the display-property isn't the right approach.